# Android, Quick question on service binding

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to find out if an activity is bound to a service? Something like `boolean isBoundToService(ServiceConnection sc)`?

Sometimes when I play around with my app I get an exception when it tries to unbind a service which is not bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's a method you can call to find this out.  However, what I've commonly seen done is to keep a boolean in the activity that tracks whether or not the service is bound.  You'd set it to true in your `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` callback and set it to false in `ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected()`.